# Replacing first whitespace in every line with a comma

Tags: python, regex

I need to perform this operation to every single line in a text file and then write it to another file. I need to remove the **first whitespace** and replace it with a comma (`,`).

However, I don't want this to happen to any other whitespace on the line. Here is a snippet from the input text file:

```
Achilles Patroclus
Achilles Triumph of Achilles in Corfu Achilleion
Achilles Antilochus
Achilles Hephaestus
Achilles Shield of Achilles
```

Comment: Great. What have you tried already?

Comment: You mean place `,` after first word i.e `Achilles` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
[",".join(line.split(" ", 1)) for line in lines]
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction! Here was my solution..

with open(f_in, 'r') as fin:
        with open(f_out, 'w') as fout:
            for line in fin:
               fout.write(",".join(line.split(" ", 1)))

Answer (score 4):

Using `re.sub` with `^([^\s]*)\s+`:

```
>>> s
'Achilles Triumph of Achilles in Corfu Achilleion'

>>> re.sub(r'^([^\s]*)\s+', r'\1, ', s)
'Achilles, Triumph of Achilles in Corfu Achilleion'
```

Comment: Nice, it works. Can you explain the search pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Well am not a python programmer but I will *try* to contribute to solution from regex point of view.

What you are trying to do is **identify** the first word and **whitespace** after it. Following regex does that job.

**Regex:** `(^\b\w*\b)(\s)`

**Flags used:**

- `g` for global search.
- `m` for multi line search.

**Explanation:**

- `(^\b\w*\b)` will capture the first word of the line.
- `(\s)` will capture the whitespace after first word. You can opt for non-capturing group too by using `?:` inside it, so it becomes `(?:\s)` or simply don't capture it.

**Replacement to do:**

- Replace matched content with `\1,`. This will put the first captured group as it is and `,` instead of a `whitespace`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iV6hF3/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use the string method `replace(old, new, [count])`.  If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

```
with open("file-path") as fin, open("new_file_path", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace(' ', ',', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a fourth parameter in `re.sub` which can be used like

```
re.sub(" ", ",", x, cnt=1)
```

`x` is the string and `cnt` indicates how many replacement you want